# PYTHON DATAFRAME - SPLIT ONE COLUMN of numbers [0,0] DATAFRAME into TWO COLUMNS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

In have a dataframe from AMAZON DATASET The dataset has a 'helpful' column which looks like this: 'helpful' :[0, 0] where the first element is a 'yes' vote and the second is a 'total' vote.

I´d like to Split this columns into two columns USING PANDAS (PYTHON).
The first column must contains only the first element. The last with the second element

```
import pandas as pd


df.head(5)

reviewerID     asin       reviewerName  helpful
0 A2VNYWOPJ13AFP 0981850006 "Customer"     [0,0]
0 A20DWVV8HML3AW 0923587406 "Customer"     [1,3]
0 A3VMADADA13AFP 0981587706 "Customer"     [0,0]
0 A28XY55TP3Q90O 0541217906 "Customer"     [2,4]
0 A5RTTREES110V3 0265478006 "Customer"     [0,0]
0 A2VNYWOPJ13AFP 0565777106 "Customer"     [1,5]


Index(['reviewerID', 'asin', 'reviewerName', 'helpful'],
      dtype='object')

df.helpful[1][0] = 1
df.helpful[1][1] = 3

Do that for all columns

pd.DataFrame(ratings['helpful'], columns = ['Yes','Vote'])

reviewerID     asin       reviewerName  helpful
0 A2VNYWOPJ13AFP 0981850006 "Customer"     [0,0]
0 A20DWVV8HML3AW 0923587406 "Customer"     [1,3]
0 A3VMADADA13AFP 0981587706 "Customer"     [0,0]
0 A28XY55TP3Q90O 0541217906 "Customer"     [2,4]
0 A5RTTREES110V3 0265478006 "Customer"     [0,0]
0 A2VNYWOPJ13AFP 0565777106 "Customer"     [1,5]

helpful dtype=obect

THE GOAL - EXPECTED RESULT

  reviewerID     asin       reviewerName  YES      TOTAL VOTE
0 A2VNYWOPJ13AFP 0981850006 "Customer"     0        0
0 A20DWVV8HML3AW 0923587406 "Customer"     1        3
0 A3VMADADA13AFP 0981587706 "Customer"     0        0
0 A28XY55TP3Q90O 0541217906 "Customer"     2        4
0 A5RTTREES110V3 0265478006 "Customer"     0        0
0 A2VNYWOPJ13AFP 0565777106 "Customer"     1        5
```

Comment: is `helpful` a column of lists or strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can split them like this:

```
df[['first','second']]=pd.DataFrame(df['helpful'].tolist(),columns=['first','second'])
```

output:

```
  helpful  first  second
0  [0, 0]      0       0
1  [1, 3]      1       3
2  [0, 0]      0       0
```

this is assuming the helpful entries are lists

EDIT - if your column is actually strings i.e. '[0,1]'

```
df['helpful'] = [eval(h) for h in df['helpful'].values]
df[['first','second']]=pd.DataFrame(df['helpful'].tolist(),columns=['first','second'])
```

same output

OR

```
df['first'] = [str(h).replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')[0] for h in df['helpful'].values]
df['second'] = [str(h).replace('[','').replace(']','').split(',')[1] for h in df['helpful'].values]
```

same output